# Can we always find an exact analytical solution(not steady state) of a first order coupled differential equation which has time dependent coefficient?

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-equations

\begin{gather}
 \begin{bmatrix} \dfrac{\partial x_1}{\partial t} \\\dfrac{\partial x_2}{\partial t}\\\dfrac{\partial x_3}{\partial t}\\\dfrac{\partial x_4}{\partial t} \end{bmatrix}
 =
  \begin{bmatrix}
    -\gamma &a_1(t) &a_2(t) &0 \\
    -a_2(t)&b_1(t)+\gamma &0 &a_2(t) \\
    -a_1(t)&0 &-b_1(t)+\gamma &a_1(t) \\
    \gamma&-a_1(t) &-a_2(t) &0 
   \end{bmatrix}
    \begin{bmatrix}
   x_{1}\\
   x_{2}\\
   x_{3}\\
   x_{4}
   \end{bmatrix}
\end{gather}
In the above equation, $\gamma$ is constant and other coefficients are time-dependent. Is there any method to solve this equation and get exact solutions of $x_1,x_2,x_3$ and $x_4$

Comment: This seems to belong into mathematics. Even there the question would be what you mean by "exact" solution? One can give a formal solution, but that does not mean that it can be expressed in terms of primitive functions. That is already not possible for most integrals.

Comment: Here, by 'exact' solution I mean to say the solution without taking any approximation

Comment: Why is the quantum-mechanics tag being used here ?  There is no apparent physics connection in your post.

Comment: This seems to be just a [matrix differential equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_differential_equation).

Comment: We can represent any function "exactly" by the symbol f(x,t), but that is not what you are looking for. The differential equations already specifies entire classes of functions "exactly", but that is meaningless. In this case you will end up with something like a matrix exponential function, if I am not mistaken. Whether that satisfies your requirement for "exactness" is a personal choice.